# How to get a onClick on a gridview to display info in 3 textfields

Tags: java, eclipse, gridview, vaadin, onclicklistener

I'm trying to achieve is when User click on a gridview and it would display that day which has 3 columns of info to display that info in textfields below it.

I'm not sure how to get it so I can click on any of the rows and have that info be shown in the textfields. Also I'm using vaadin and working with eclipse.

Comment: Nothing so far, I thought that I could use a onClickListener but I'm now sure how that would work with that because I dont know how to access that.

Answer (score 0):

### Editing data inside the grid

As you can read in [Book of Vaadin - Grid](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.grid.html), editing data in grid can be achieved inplace

> Grid supports line-based editing, where double-clicking a row opens the row editor. In the editor, the input fields can be edited, as well as navigated with Tab and Shift+Tab keys. The editor has a Save button that commits the data item to the container data source and closes the editor. If validation fails, an error is displayed and the user can correct the inputs. A Cancel button discards the changes and exits the editor.
>   To enable editing, you need to call setEditorEnabled(true) for the grid.

```
grid.setEditorEnabled(true);
```

[image: In place editing example]

As explained further in the mentioned post, you can also customize editor fields and save and cancel buttons.

### Editing data outside the grid

If you want to show data of selected row in some external components such as textboxes, you should add `ItemClickListener` to your grid. From `ItemClickEvent` received you can then get various information as the row and column. You can easily use those to read that row data and display it somewhere else for editing. However, I would reccomend editing the data inplace inside the grid editor, as it is simpler, more convenient for the user and already implemented. It is not necessary to reinvent the wheel.

```
   grid.addItemClickListener(new ItemClickEvent.ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
            Item clickedItem = event.getItem();
            //Your logic here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way to save my changes or would I need to set up a database for that? Also is there way were I could double click the row and have that info (Name, City, and Year) show in textfields?

Comment: When you click save button (on the picture), your edits will be saved to DataSource of your grid. No need to set up a database. I will update my answer regarding showing value in textfields

Comment: Yup your right, that save did work. And yeah all I need now is the displaying the info in the textfields.

Comment: I noticed that when I hit the save button it will save but it doesn't update the index or years in your example. If you know what I mean.

Comment: What should the logic be?

Comment: Whatever you need to do. Assign value from that item to a value of TextField for editing etc.

Comment: Okay, but I dont know what code I would use for that. My textfield is called index. So how would I start this off? with the editor.